# Google Maps showing blank layout

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map activity, using Google Maps. I have created a project on Google Cloud Platform, generated api key, also a finger print. A I have added these to my application.

The map has showed up for me, but after a few days of developing de application, when I returned to that Activity I have realized..my Google Maps showing only a blank page..with my custom markers on it. I re-generated the api key..but nothing changed.

I have found some tutorials on YoTube..already tried some advices from here (StackOverflow).. but nothing helped.

Code:

build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="@string/map_key" />
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
<activity android:name="hu.selfree.discount.MapActivity" />
```

Activity

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        moveCameraToDefault();
    }


don't know what to show here really
```

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gns.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/google_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-136dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/my_location_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/googleMapsBlue"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/back_to_hungary_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/googleMapsBlue"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_map_fab"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/my_location_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/my_location_fab" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/map_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.GoogleMapsProgressBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/google_map"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/google_map" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you add below tag in the manifest?

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

add it and try again, maybe it works.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not going to be marked as the answer. Still nothing, just a blank gray page..with my custom markers on it.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem now. Were you able to fix this @csirkeautomata